# what is wrong with this if condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What is wrong with this IF condition?
When I am giving EEID value as 123456 it should not come into this condition.
But I see that it is coming.
Can somebody let me know what am I doing wrong?

```
if ((EEID.value.length != 6) || (EEID.value.length != 11)) {
        alert(EEID.value.length); //This shows that the value length = 6
        alert("Your Member ID must be a 6 digit or 11 digit number.");
        EEID.focus();
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: Use AND instead of OR. `EEID.value.length != 11` is `true` for `123456`, and `false OR true` is `true`.

Comment: But the value length could be either 6 or 11.

Comment: It's always going to pass.  You're basically asking if the length is not 6 and 11 at the same time

Comment: @Ditty: Yes, that's why you have to check that it is **not** 6 **and** **not** 11 (equivalent to **not** (6 **or** 11)). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The condition is satisfied because EEID.value.length is not 11. The or (||) allows either != 6 or != 11 to satisfy the if condition.

You need to change the or (||) to an and (&&) as such:

```
if ((EEID.value.length != 6) && (EEID.value.length != 11)) {
    alert(EEID.value.length);
    alert("Your Member ID must be a 6 digit or 11 digit number.");
    EEID.focus();
    return false;
}
```

This way, the if condition is satisfied only when EEID.value.length is not 6 and not 11.

Comment: Thank you for removing that pointless comment that he had. Not sure what it was pertaining too. Very nice answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

What you originally have, `(!P || !Q)`, returns true all the time, as `EEID.value.length` cannot be both `6` and `11` at the same time. When one is false, the other is true, and vice versa, thus it is always true.

Take a look at [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), or more precisely that

```
(!P && !Q) == !(P || Q)
```

Which is similar to what you have, but states that the condition is true if `EEID.value.length` is neither `6` *or* `11`. (**Note** that I would prefer the right side as it only negates once.) So, basically, you can write your conditions like

```
if ((EEID.value.length != 6) && (EEID.value.length != 11)) {
```

or

```
if (!(EEID.value.length == 6 || EEID.value.length == 11)) {
```

Comment: +1, the last if statement best represents the sentence "if EEID.value.length is not 6 or 11" and should be used.